# My friend neither/Neither has my friend

Tags: neither-nor

Is the using of "neither" in this dialogue correct?

-I haven't seen the film yet.

-My friend neither.

It could be "Neither has my friend." But I want to find out if that using is also correct.

What about this one?

-Neither has my friend seen the film, nor have I.

Answer (score 1):

"My friend neither" is awkward in American English, though not incorrect.
We sometimes say referring to ourselves, "me neither," which is accepted and not awkward.

Referring to others, it is common to use:
Neither has my friend.
My friend hasn't either.
My friend has not either.

Comment: Can I also say "I haven't seen the film yet, nor has my friend"?

Comment: @Bora Yes, it is correct. The use of "nor" is becoming less common though in informal speech. More often you'll hear, "I haven't seen the film yet, and my friend hasn't either."

Answer (score 0):

When a negative statement has been made, you can use neither to show that this statement also applies to another person or thing.

You put neither at the beginning of the clause, followed by an auxiliary verb, a modal, or be, then the subject. You can also use "nor" in the same way with the same meaning.

'I didn't invite them.' – 'Neither did I.'
If your printer does not work, neither will your fax or copier.
Douglas can't do it, and nor can Gavin.

I haven't seen the film yet. 
Nor has my friend, sounds good to me.

Comment: What if I say? "Neither has my friend seen the film, nor have I."

Comment: It is grammatical sentence. You can say so. Anyway, what thing confuses you here?

Comment: I couldn't see any sentence like that. I was trying to find out if it was correct.

Comment: Check my answer. There's an example, which one? This one: Douglas can't do it and nor can Gavin. Did you see it?

Comment: "Neither has my friend seen the film, nor have I." It is grammatically correct as @Idon'tknowwhoIam. wrote, but it sounds very awkward, too formal, and outdated in American English.